# Rename javascript object key

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have a multidimensional object like this:

```
var elements = {
    front: {
        "1": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/pig.png)",
        },
        "2": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/star.png)",
        },
        "3": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/fish.png)",
        }
    },
    top: {},
    left: {},
    right: {}
};
```

and I need to switch two elements in this object so I do:

```
var temp = elements[front][2];
elements[front][2] = elements[front][3];
elements[front][3] = temp;
```

which gives me (switches fish and star - but only the properties not the object key):

```
var elements = {
    front: {
        "1": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/pig.png)",
        },
        "2": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/fish.png)",
        },
        "3": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/star.png)",
        }
    },
    top: {},
    left: {},
    right: {}
};
```

**How can I also rename the object key?**

Desired result:

```
var elements = {
    front: {
        "1": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/pig.png)",
        },
        "3": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/fish.png)",
        },
        "2": {
           "backgroundImage": "url(images/elements/star.png)",
        }
    },
    top: {},
    left: {},
    right: {}
};
```

Comment: The desired result is the same as your original object. Properties are not sorted. If you want the images to be in a specific order, you have to use an array.

Comment: @FelixKling I know they don't have an order but I use this object later on in a loop to render the background images in html - and the properties get rendered one after another and the fake order matters to me.

Comment: So, you are using a `for...in` loop to iterate over the properties? The order in which they are iterated over differs from browser to browser. What you want to do is technically impossible.

Comment: Not really - I do fill it in an array later on - this is just some simplified code - my main question is how to switch two key names in an object. I'm aware of all the problems that can come up if I did that.

Comment: The thing is that you didn't switch anything. The original object is *exactly the same* as the one you want. A property doesn't have a position in an object, hence `{a:1, b:2}` is the same as `{b:2, a:1}`. "Renaming" a property would only make sense if you want to take an existing property value and assign it to a new property name. But you are not doing that, your `name -> value` mapping stays the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sort the keys in your object but you can't do this because object don't have an order. This is what the JavaScript spec says.

There are some cases where unexpected things happen if you rely on a sorting.

In Chrome, if you define this object:

```
var a = {
    a: "b",
    1: 2
};
```

You will get

```
var a = {
    1: 2,
    a: "b"
};
```

instead (which is the same object, because again, objects don't have order).

`for .. in` loops on objects are very misleading in the sense that you *think* they have an order but really you could write a valid JavaScript implementation that randomizes the order every time you do a `for .. in`

If you want to iterate over your keys in a specific order, for instance: alphabetically or natural sort, you first have to convert your object to an array (which does have an order) and then iterate over that.

You can imagine a function like:

```
object_iterate(my_object, function (key, value) {
    // do things
}, natural_order_key_sort);
```

Comment: I don't want to sort the keys - all I'm asking is how can I rewrite the key name - my code rewrites all the content of the object except for it's name - how can I target it's name and rename it?

Comment: There is no rename. You can delete a key by `delete obj["property name"]` and set it through normal assign. and again, there is no sorting.

Comment: Got the idea - actually solved this is another way now so the question is quite silly now but I'll leave it if someone stumbles upon same problem as me.